# Why is this proof that the group operation on $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is well defined?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $g_1,g'_1, g_2, g'_2$ be loops on a topological space $X$ at $x_0 \in X$. Suppose that $[g_1]=[g'_1]$ and $[g_2]=[g'_2]$. Then let a map $F: [0,1]\times [0,1] \to X$ be defined as 
$$ F = \Big\{
  \begin{array}
     \,F_1(2t,s), & 0\leq t \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
      F_2(2t-1,s), &   \frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1 \
  \end{array}
$$where $F_1:[0,1]\times [0,1] \to X$ is a homotopy between $g_1,g'_1$ and $F_2:[0,1]\times [0,1] \to X$ is a homotopy between $g_2,g'_2$ and where the homotopies $F_1, F_2$ map $(0,s)$ and $(1,s)$ to $x_0$ for all $x_0 \in X$. **Thus**, the proof says, $[g_1 \cdot g_2 ] = [g'_1 \cdot g'_2]$ showing that the group operation on  $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is well defined.

**Why the last statement is a proof that the group operation is well defined?** I understand everything up to the word "thus".

**P.S.** Geometrically or pictorially I do understand very well why $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is a group. So a connection to this in the previous proof would help a lot.

Comment: $F$ is a homotopy between $g_1 \cdot g_2$ and $g_1' \cdot g_2'$. So the homotopy class of the concatenated map is independent of the choice of representatives for the two homotopy classes you are multiplying in $\pi_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the definition $[g_1][g_2] = [g_1\cdot g_2]$ might not be well defined. Namely, we must check that if we have $g_{1}'\neq g_1$ such that they are homotopy equivalent, then we must have $[g_1\cdot g_2] = [g_1][g_2] = [g_1'][g_2] = [g_1'\cdot g_2]$. Similarly for $g_2$ we must do the same, which can be combined into saying that $[g_1\cdot g_2] = [g_1'\cdot g_2']$. The proof constructs a homotopy between these two maps, which proves this statement.

Comment: Hi, I am confused with what you are saying. I do not see why having $g_1\neq q'_1$ but being in the same homotopy class requires to check that $[g_1 \cdots g_2]= \ldots$. I do not understand the logic here. :/

Comment: Well if $[g_1] = [g_1']$, then we must have $[g_1\cdot g_2] = [g_1][g_2] = [g_1'][g_2] = [g_1'\cdot g_2]$. As in the answer. Does that help?

Comment: Hi. I still struggle to see what you mean but I will think about it a bit more. In the meanwhile, there is a nice way to "see" it. I drew some arbitrary topological space with some curves and next to it I drew two squares ($[0,1]\times [0.1]$). Then I made it to represent two homotopies. One square was $g_1 \to g'_1$ and the other was $g_2 \to g'_2$. Then I "glued" these two squares and then it is easy to see that indeed $[g_1]\cdot [g_2] = [g_1 \cdot g_2] = [g'_1 \cdot g'_2] = [g'_1] \cdot [g'_2] $